# File to byte [] in spring integration flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a part of my project where I'm polling a file from FTP and I want to convert or transform the file content to byte[] and save it in the database as byte[] , I found a FileToByteArrayTransformer but not sure how I can use it.

Can some one please enlighten me on how to use it?

Here is my code:

```
   @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow ftpInboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(ftpSessionFactory())
                                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                                .remoteDirectory(appProperties.getFtp().getRemoteDirectory())
                                .patternFilter(appProperties.getFtp().getFilter())
                                .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
                                .localDirectory(new File("inbound"))
                                .temporaryFileSuffix(appProperties.getFtp().getTemporaryFileSuffix()),
                        e -> e.id("ftpInboundAdapter")
                                .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(appProperties.getFtp().getPollerDelay()))
                                .autoStartup(true))
                .<File, byte[]>transform(p -> new FileToByteArrayTransformer().transform(p.getAbsoluteFile()))
                .handle( p -> {
                    log.info("After transform " + p);
                    CustomerFile customerFile = CustomerFile.builder()
                            .content(p)
                            .customerFileType(CustomerFileType.ORDER_BOOK)
                            .build();
                    customerFileService.saveCustomerFile(customerFile);

                }

//                .publishSubscribeChannel(s ->
//                        s.subscribe(h -> h
//                                .handle(p -> {
//                                    byte[] payload = SerializationUtils.serialize(p.getPayload());
//                                    CustomerFile customerFile = CustomerFile.builder()
//                                            .content(payload)
//                                            .customerFileType(CustomerFileType.ORDER_BOOK)
//                                            .build();
//                                    customerFileService.saveCustomerFile(customerFile);
//                                }, e -> e.advice(expressionAdvice()))
//                        )
//                )
                /*  .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(ftpSessionFactory())
                          .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                          .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                          .remoteDirectory("/ftp/GE/Inbound/history"))*/
                .get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FileToByteArrayTransformer` is a `GenericTransformer<Message<?>, Message<?>>` implementation. That's one.

On the other hand there is respective DSL API:

```
/**
 * Populate the {@link MessageTransformingHandler} instance for the provided
 * {@link GenericTransformer}. Use {@link #transform(Class, GenericTransformer)} if
 * you need to access the entire message.
 * @param genericTransformer the {@link GenericTransformer} to populate.
 * @param <S> the source type - 'transform from'.
 * @param <T> the target type - 'transform to'.
 * @return the current {@link IntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 * @see org.springframework.integration.transformer.MethodInvokingTransformer
 * @see org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor
 */
public <S, T> B transform(GenericTransformer<S, T> genericTransformer) {
```

So, what you need in that place is just this:

```
.transform(new FileToByteArrayTransformer())
```

Comment: If I use `.tranform(new FileToByteArrayTransformer())` then in the handle I need to cast the payload to `byte[]` ? or how can use the output of the transform to save in the database? @Artem Bilan

Comment: Of course you have to cast. The point of messaging is to be type-agnostic and it is already up to internal contract of the specific endpoint to expect this or that type. We cannot carry over the result type to the input of the next. That's not what messaging is designed for.

Comment: sounds great thanks @Artem Bilan